# How to automatically trigger a build after a PR is completed in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Is there a way I can set up a build in Azure DevOps to automatically run every time a PR is merged and completed and contains a specific keyword in the name? for example: `"Some PR name here [RUN_BUILD_123]"`

**Edit:**
The reason for this is because I have different builds on top of the same branch so instead of triggering all the builds I just want to trigger those that I know need to be rebuilt based on the particular projects getting changed.

Comment: i'd be really surprised if its possible without some hacks

Comment: @hugh-lin-msft The solutions proposed are technically correct but do not solve my problem because I have different builds on the same branch and I don't want all of them to run when the changes are merged. Instead I want only one particular build to run. Currently I do it manually every time the PRs are completed, so I guess I will have to keep doing it that way. Thank anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A PR has a target-branch. If you want to trigger a build after a PR is completed just configure a build with a ci-trigger for that target-branch. You can't check for certain keywords in the PR-name unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Agree with D.J. For detailed setting, you can check the **Enable continous intergration** option in the **Triggers** settings, then select the target branch you want ci-trigger build in the **Branch filters**.This will automatically trigger the build after pr is completed.
But you can't do it if you want to include special keywords in pr name.

Answer (score 0):

Topic is a bit old, but if there is anyone who want's to archive this stumbling over this topic - here is my approach how I would solve this:

The basic of all are scripted pipelines, so if you still do it in the GUI - that's wasted time. Create a .yml build and put it into your Git. The M$ documentation is really helpful with this.

1. Create the trigger for your branch

Put this on the first line, so the pipeline will be executed when master (or your branch) has a new commit

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
```

2. Read out the commit message via the VSTS variables
3. Trigger the builds, based on their ID via REST API (you can use the pipeline token for authentication)